# How to Import Selenium in Google Cloud Platform Virtual Machine?

Tags: python, selenium, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have created a Virtual Machine in Google Cloud Platform. The VM does let me run Python code, but it does not allow me to import selenium.

I have seen several videos where they use docker to import selenium, but it hasn't worked for me.

Does someone know how to import selenium into your Google Cloud Platform VM?

When I run this code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/home/juan_vecinodeharo/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juan_vecinodeharo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/home/juan_vecinodeharo/chromedriver.exe': 'C:/home/juan_vecinodeharo/chromedriver.exe'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello world.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/home/juan_vecinodeharo/chromedriver.exe")
  File "/home/juan_vecinodeharo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/juan_vecinodeharo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

As you can see it says that I don not have a path, but in the other hand I have already done that in the code.

Comment: In order to use selenium, you'll need to install both 1) the webdriver binary compatible with the OS of the VM and 2) the Python library. Pretty good coverage of the topic at this link:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/

Comment: What are the error messages you are receiving and what have you tried so far? Did you use any guide on your setup? Please provide a more detailed explanation on your troubleshooting.

Comment: @AlexG I have done a "pip install -U selenium" and my selenium has been imported in './.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages'  but now I can not find my web-driver path. I also do not know if I need to install explicitly chrome in my Debian VM. I am new in GCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this selenium option it will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
```